# problem while placing alert on checkbox checked in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, checkbox

i need to check if checkbox 1 or 2 is clicked.
error : only background is printing while clicking any checbox and pressing button

```js
function onlyOne(checkbox) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check')
  checkboxes.forEach((item) => {
    if (item !== checkbox) item.checked = false;
  });
}

function run() {

  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check')
  if (document.getElementById('c1').checked) {
    alert("background");
  } else if (document.getElementById('c1').checked) {
    alert("foreground");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="c1" value="background" onclick="onlyOne(this)">background</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="c2" value="foreground" onclick="onlyOne(this)">foreground</input>
<input type="button" value="button" onclick="run()">
```

Comment: In the second statment you write c1 again instead of c2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second statment you write c1 again instead of c2

```js
function onlyOne(checkbox) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check')
  checkboxes.forEach((item) => {
    if (item !== checkbox) item.checked = false;
  });
}

function run() {

  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check')
  if (document.getElementById('c1').checked) {
    alert("background");
  } else if (document.getElementById('c2').checked) {
    alert("foreground");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="c1" value="background" onclick="onlyOne(this)">background</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="c2" value="foreground" onclick="onlyOne(this)">foreground</input>
<input type="button" value="button" onclick="run()">
```

---

Instead of use your method why don't use radio and print the radio checked like:

```js
document.getElementById('run').addEventListener('click',AlertMe);

function AlertMe() {

  document.getElementsByName('check').forEach( (el) =>{
    if(el.checked === true) alert(el.value);
  });
 
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="check" value="background">background</input>
<input type="radio" name="check" value="foreground">foreground</input>
<input type="button" value="button" id='run'>
```

Comment: i cannot use radio because this is a home work question

Comment: oh ok :) However, I recommend that you use addEventListener rather than inline function

Answer (score 0):

It's miss named ID of element for foreground

```
    function run(){
        
    [...]
        else if(document.getElementById('c1').checked){
            alert("foreground");
    [...]
```

it should be:

```
   [...]
        else if(document.getElementById('c2').checked){
            alert("foreground");
   [...]
```